# I am using django tables 2 and trying to export my table following the official documentation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have followed the official documentation of django tables 2 but it is not working I dont know why

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django_tables2 import RequestConfig
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from .models import Customer
from .tables import CustomerTable
from .tables import TableView
from django_tables2.export.export import TableExport

def user_profile(request):

    table= CustomerTable(Customer.objects.all())
    RequestConfig(request,paginate={'per_page':15}).configure(table)

    return render(request, 'home.html', {'table': table})


def TableView(request):
    table = CustomerTable(Customer.objects.all())

    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)

    export_format = request.GET.get('_export', None)
    if TableExport.is_valid_format(export_format):
        exporter = TableExport(export_format, table)
        return exporter.response('table.{}'.format(export_format))

    return render(request, 'table.html', {
        'table': table
    })
```

my html template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}





{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% load querystring from django_tables2 %}




<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>List of Customers</title>

</head>
<body>

    {% querystring '_export'='csv' %}home

    {% for format in table.export_formats %}
<a href="{% querystring '_export'=format %}">
    download  <code>.{{ format }}</code>
</a>
    {% endfor %}

    <p margin-bottom:500px;>  </p>

    <div style="width: 2500px; height: 600px; overflow-y: scroll;">
        <div id ="users">
            <input class="search" placeholder="Search" />



    {% render_table table %}
    {% endblock %}
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', user_profile, name="user_profile"),
    url(r'^$', TableView, name="TableView"),

]
```

tables.py

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from .models import Customer
from django_tables2.export.views import ExportMixin

from .models import Customer

class CustomerTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        template = 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html'

class TableView(ExportMixin, tables.SingleTableView):
    table_class = CustomerTable
    model = Customer
    template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html'
```

I have a feeling something is wrong with the way I have defined urls.py but i cannot figure out what is wrong

Comment: You must explain what exactly is not working.

Comment: on the website i am not getting a button to export data as csv only "?_export=csv"  is written at the beginning but not doing anything

Comment: Hey @crazyknight, I have the same problem, I only see  "?_export=csv" on the the html page. Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a note [in the documentation on exporting](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/export.html) saying:

> This example assumes you define a list of possible export formats on your table instance in attribute `export_formats`.

So you need to add the desired export formats to a list on your table like this:

```
class CustomerTable(tables.Table):
    export_formats = ['csv', 'xls']

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        template = 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html'
```

You an also define the list in a context variable for your template, if you prefer that. There is no 'right' in this.

Comment: Works fine. Better use xlsx instead of xls format

Answer (score -1):

So I also banged my head against the wall a little bit on this, and then in a moment of clarity it hit me, you need wrap the query string tag like this in the template file

```
<a href="{% querystring '_export'='csv' %}">download as csv</a>
```